# How to propagate model changes to a modal?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my angularjs app I store my data in $rootScope, like this:

```
$rootScope.users = [{id: 1, name: 'Bob'}, {id: 2, name: 'Alice'}];
```

At some point I get a change from a server:

```
function changeFromServer(user) {
    for (var i=0; i < $rootScope.users.length; ++i) {
        if ($rootScope.users[i].id == user.id) {
            $rootScope.users[i] = user;
            break;
        }
    }
    $rootScope.apply();
}
```

This works fine in most cases. But in some cases I bring up modal dialogs, like this:

```
function changeUser(user) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/show.html',
        controller: 'UserModalCtrl',
        resolve: {
            user: function() {
                return user;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When this modal is showing and a change comes from the server, the list of users will be updated as it should, BUT, the modal is not updated. Why is that? It's as if it has a copy of the object or something.

Comment: I recommend not using the root scope, but a service to store, retrieve and share the data.

Comment: Yes, I will refactor my code to do that one day. But it will not solve the issue here, will it?

Comment: I am pretty sure it will, however you have to inject the service both into the modal's controller and your main controller. Another alternative that I can think of is if you add `scope:$scope` to your modal config. This creates a child scope inside the modal that could inherit the data.

Comment: It seems doing $rootScope.users[i] = user; is not working so well. Doing angular.copy(user, $rootScope.users[i]) will preserve the object and update it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're doing your modal, but a custom directive, with transclude setted to true and no isolated scope, would help you to share your users from the controller scope with your modal.

To display your modal, just add a ng-show attribute with a flag refering a prop in your controller:

```
<div ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <my-modal ng-show="showModal">
        <span ng-bind-html="user.name" ng-repeat="user in users"></span>
        <button ng-click="showModal = !showModal">Close</button>
    </my-modal>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'userProviderService', function($scope, userProviderService) {
    $scope.userListUpdated = false;
    // Init the userlist in the service!
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.$watch('userProviderService.users', function(newValue, oldValue){
         $scope.users = newValue;
         $scope.showModal = true;
    });
}])
```

Comment: He is using Angular UI Bootstrap modals http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal